# Can't figure out how to print the least squares error

Tags: python, numpy, regression, least-squares

I wrote some code to find the best fitting line for a couple of data points using the analytical solution to least squares. Now I would like to print the error between the actual data and my estimated line, but I have no idea how to compute it. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array(((0,1),
             (1,1),
             (2,1),
             (3,1)))

b = np.array((1,2,0,3), ndmin = 2 ).T

xstar = np.matmul( np.matmul( np.linalg.inv( np.matmul(A.T, A) ), A.T), b)

print(xstar)

plt.scatter(A.T[0], b)
u = np.linspace(0,3,20)
plt.plot(u, u * xstar[0] + xstar[1], 'b-')
```

Comment: When you say 'print the error' do you mean to show the plot?

Comment: No, the plot is fine. With the error I mean getting the difference between the points and my line estimate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already plotted the predictions from the linear regression. So from the value of the prediction, you can calculate the "sum of square errors (SSE)" or the "mean square error (MSE)" as follows:

```
y_prediction = u * xstar[0] + xstar[1]
SSE = np.sum(np.square(y_prediction - b))
MSE = np.mean(np.square(y_prediction - b))
print(SSE)
print(MSE)
```

An aside note. You might want to use `np.linalg.pinv` as that is a more numerically stable matrix inverse operator.

Comment: Thank you, this works! I have a question, I am also plotting a curve to this same data, and the error is larger, is that normal?

Comment: Depends what curve you are plotting. If you are using a polynomial "least squares" curve and you are fitting it to the same data that you use to calculate the error, the error must decrease. If you are using some other curve, or if you are calculating the error on some other data then sure it is possible that the error is larger :). Not sure that answers you question.

Comment: I suggest you read the section on Linear Regression in "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" by  Daniela Witten, Gareth James, Robert Tibshirani, and Trevor Hastie

Answer (score 0):

Note that `numpy` has a function for it, calles [`lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) (i.e. least-squares), that returns the residuals as well as the solution, so you don't have to implement it yourself:

```
xstar, residuals = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
MSE = np.mean(residuals)
SSE = np.sum(residuals)
```

try it!

Comment: Are you sure that the above calculation for MSE is correct? `residuals` is the sum of squared residuals per numpy's documentation. This means that you need to divide residuals by b.size to get MSE. Right?

Comment: Yes - and .mean divides by size, as opposed to .sum (or an I misreading your question?)